# Android scrollable activity with two listviews

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-xml

I have 2 listviews, an adapter for each one of them, I need to show it in one activity, like the contacts android app, the problem is, I can't make the entire activity scroll, see the pictures to understand better what I'm looking for, here is mu xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TELEFONES"
            android:textColor="#00CC66"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EMAILS"
            android:textColor="#00CC66"
            android:id="@+id/textView"

            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"


            >

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: This is the current layout] [image: This is what I'm trying to achieve]

This is what I'm looking for, scroll the entire activity

Comment: Why do you have a RelativeLayout as the only child for your LinearLayout ? Also, it's unclear to me if what you want to achieve is the first or second example you provide... If it's the second, having 2 ListViews is probably not going to work.

Comment: Put all in one expandable listview and you are done.

Comment: @2Dee I'm want to achieve the second example

Comment: @greenapps How can I join 2 listviews into one expandable?

Comment: Have you ever experimented with an expandable listview? No? Then try here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: @greenapps can you show me please how would I do that, I'm very new to android development

Comment: Just make that example first. All code is ready. All is in the article. If the example works then you can later adapt it for your needs. The example has `three listviews combined` as you can see on the picture there. Further you did not answer my question.